# Simple Search Form

Tags: simple-search

I am using this code which I thought was right.

```
{exp:search:simple_form channel="work" search_in="everywhere" role="search" id="search-form"}
                  <label class="screen-reader-text" for="search">Search</label>
                  <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="search" title="Enter keyword">
                  <input type="submit" id="search-submit" title="Search it" value="→">
                {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

However I get an error (see attached). Does anyone have any ideas to what I am doing wrong in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only certain [input fields](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/simple.html#input-fields) are supported and if you're using keywords for example then you need to ensure that the name attribute is set:

```
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords">
```

That should yield some results.

Comment: Many thanks I will follow the documentation.

Comment: No problem, post back if you're stuck. Don't forget to mark the answer correct if it solved the issue.